# Accessing a function inside a class function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How would I call darkness and put parameters in it?

```
class imageProcesses {
   class func DefaultProcesses() {
       func CompleteDarkness(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
           let dark = Darken(124, image: image)
           return dark
       }
   }
}
```

iv'e tried this:

```
ImageProcessor.DefaultProcesses().CompleteDarkness(image!)
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a nested function from outside. Move it out to a class function:

```
class imageProcesses {
   class func CompleteDarkness(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
       let dark = Darken(124, image: image)
       return dark
    }

   class func DefaultProcesses() {
       // ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you declaring a function inside of a function anyway?

```
class imageProcesses {
   class func DefaultProcesses(image: UIImage) {
         completeDarkness(image: image)//calls completeDarkness.
   }

   func CompleteDarkness(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
       let dark = Darken(124, image: image)
       return dark
   }
}
```

Later call

```
ImageProcessor.DefaultProcesses(image: image!)//Now calling DefaultProcesses will run Complete Darkness and anything else you put in there.
```

Comment: thanks, but i'm looking for a way to put it under a function that i can specifically put defaults in, but still in my class imageProcesses, is there's still a way to do that?

Comment: Yes pass in an image to default  processes and call it from there. I'll update my answer.

Comment: BTW, please use camel case for function names i.e. completeDarknes() instead of CompleteDarkness. Save leading capital camel case for class names like i.e. imageProcesses should be ImageProcesses. Its best practice in apple swift and objc.

Comment: there will be about 4 more default functions in there and i only want one of them to run, if i keep the complete darkness func inside the defaultProcesses func would i call it like ImageProcessor.DefaultProcesses(image!).CompleteDarkness
because i tried it and it didn't work

Comment: if not it's not too important, i'll make them all into class func's and throw default into the front of the name ex: DefaultDarkness, DefaultBrightness etc

Answer (score 0):

Think this is what you want you can stick that in the play ground and have a go with it

```
func Darken(input:Int, image:UIImage) -> UIImage{
  return UIImage()
}

class ImageProcesses {
  class func DefaultProcesses() -> ((UIImage) -> UIImage){
    func CompleteDarkness(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
      let dark = Darken(124, image: image)
      return dark
    }
    return CompleteDarkness
  }
}
let image = UIImage()

ImageProcesses.DefaultProcesses()(image)
```